# Can we rewrite the pnl of a continuous hedge option as the time average of the volatility weighted by the square gamma?

Tags: black-scholes, hedging, pnl

From what I understand of El Karoui BS Robustness Formula, we can write the PnL of a continuously hedged option as the time average of the volatility weighted by the square gamma, is that right?
$$PnL = \sum_{t=0}^T \sigma(t,S_t) * \Gamma^2 $$

Comment: More like $$ PnL = \int_0^T \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(t,S_t,\sigma) S_t^2 \left( \sigma_r^2 - \sigma^2\right) dt $$ where $\sigma_r^2$ is the realised quadratic variation of log-prices and $\sigma^2$ is the hedging vol with a delta hedge ratio (and here gamma) calculated under BS.

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense, thank you. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you're referring to is actually
$$ P\&L_{[0,T]} = \int_0^T \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(t,S_t,\sigma) S_t^2 \left( (\sigma_t^r)^2 - \sigma^2\right) dt $$
which is the total P&L of a continuously delta hedged long option portfolio, where $(\sigma_t^r)^2$ is the realised quadratic variation of log-prices over $[t, t+dt[$ and $\sigma^2$ is the hedging vol, that is, the volatility with which the Greeks are calculated, here under BS model.